# I would like to extract words before ' & " using grep

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

For Example I have a codes that contains the "fab fa-" set of strings

```
"fab fa-123" -> fab fa-123
'fab fa-123' -> fab fa-123
```

Now in unix, I want to extract all fab fa-character and numbers before special character " or '.

I'm using the regex,

```
grep -r -o -h 'fab fa-.*' > filename.txt
```

The result is like this:

```
fab fa-123"blahblah
fab fa-123'blahblah
```

I would like to extract words before `" and '`. How can I do this?

I need your help. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, what is the meaning of -> ??? does it mean "newline" ? If you have more than one line as input and more than one line as output, please write like they appear in terminal, ie: as multiple lines

Comment: I would like to extract words from "fab fa-123" to fab fa-123 without " "

Comment: Does it have to be `grep` or could you use `sed`? For your specific examples you could use `grep -ow '[[:alnum:][:blank:]-]*'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that there's pattern like this "fab fa-123-123" Can I extract words fab fa-???-??? only without " " using sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -r -o "[^\"\']*" inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
grep -o '^[^"'"']*"
```

? The pattern here would be `^[^"']*`, but since quotes have a special meaning for the shell, I enclosed the first half of the pattern into single and the second half into double quotes. An alternative would be to backslash-escape the quotes:

```
grep -o "^[^\"']*"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used this code like this: grep -r -o -h 'fab fa^[^\"']*', however the code does not work. I'm sorry to say that I'm a newbie so could you edit this code?

Comment: @hiyo: Compare to my code: You used single quotes for the outer quotes. I used double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried, but it does not work...Thanks for your time and efforts!

Comment: @hiyo: Post the code you have now, and the result you get. If it works for me, it should work for you too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. grep -r -o "fab fa^[^\"']*" * The result was nothing shown :)

Comment: The expression does not make sense! You are searching for a literal caret (^) inside your string, while I was anchoring the regexp at the beginning! If you just change a proposed solution without understanding it, it is no surprise that it won't work. If you want to match everything which starts with _fab fa_ at the beginning of the line, it is  `grep -o "^fab fa[^\"']*"`.

Comment: @hiyo : Read [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for an explanation of the caret.

Comment: @user1923328 I appreciate it! Thank you!! Have a good one :) Actually, I installed Shell on Windows 10 today, so I'm pretty NEWBIE and thank you! :)